# Remove pattern within a column if present in a list in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
COL1            COL2 
Element1_VAL1   A
Element2_VAL2   B
Something_lima3 C 
Something_logit5 D
```

and  list such as:

```
the_list=['_VAL1','_VAL2','_lima3']
```

And I would like to remove from `COL1,` all matching patterns within `the_list` and get:

```
COL1             COL2 
Element1         A
Element2         B
Something        C 
Something_logit5 D
```

Here is the dataframe in dict format :

```
{'COL1': {0: 'Element1_VAL1', 1: 'Element2_VAL2', 2: 'Something_lima3', 3: 'Something_logit5'}, 'COL2 ': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}}
```

Comment: Why row 3 has lima? Shouldnt it be only Something

Comment: oups, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `replace()`, but modified slightly:

```
df['new'] = df['COL1'].str.replace('|'.join(the_list), '',regex=True)

print(df)

               COL1 COL2                new
0     Element1_VAL1     A          Element1
1     Element2_VAL2     B          Element2
2   Something_lima3     C         Something
3  Something_logit5     D  Something_logit5
```

This `'|'.join(the_list)` will `join` all the different elements in your `list` with `|`, which `str.replace` accepts and reads as `or`. So if any of those substrings are spotted, it will replace them `''`.

Comment: There's no need to do the join and force a regex format, the purpose of `replace()` accepting lists is the fact that you can pass it without the need to do any aggregation

Comment: Yes you are right. I just tested it. The reason why your answer was not working was the the fact that you did not include ```regex = True```. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `replace()` which is very helpful because it allows you to pass a list of elements to be replaced with a single element (blank for this case) and avoid multiple calls of `.str.replace()`. Try:

```
df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].replace(the_list,'',regex=True)
```

Comment: Hello, it does not work for me, the element to be removed are still there ...

Comment: I added the dataframe in dict format for you to test the script you used @Celius

Comment: Thanks for the edit I just missed the `regex=True` parameter